# Countdown Timer to Add extra 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have created a countdown timer and am trying to add 2 minutes into the existing timer to extend the timer.

My Code

```js
function CountDownTimer(duration, granularity) {
  this.duration = duration;
  this.granularity = granularity || 1000;
  this.tickFtns = [];
  this.running = false;
}

CountDownTimer.prototype.start = function() {
  if (this.running) {
    return;
  }
  this.running = true;
  var start = Date.now(),
    that = this,
    diff, obj;

  (function timer() {
    diff = that.duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    if (diff > 0) {
      setTimeout(timer, that.granularity);
    } else {
      diff = 0;
      that.running = false;
    }

    obj = CountDownTimer.parse(diff);
    that.tickFtns.forEach(function(ftn) {
      ftn.call(this, obj.minutes, obj.seconds);
    }, that);
  }());
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.onTick = function(ftn) {
  if (typeof ftn === 'function') {
    this.tickFtns.push(ftn);
  }
  return this;
};

CountDownTimer.prototype.expired = function() {
  return !this.running;
};

CountDownTimer.parse = function(seconds) {
  return {
    'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
    'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
  };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  var display = document.querySelector('#time'),
    //timer = new CountDownTimer(600);
    timer = new CountDownTimer(125); // for debug
  timer.onTick(format).onTick(restart).start();

  function restart() {
    if (this.expired()) {
      alert("Expired");
    }
  }

  function format(minutes, seconds) {
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    if (minutes < 2) {
      if (counter == 0) {
        alert("Extending Time");
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="time"></span> minutes
```

I managed to trigger an event that after 2 minutes will show an alert that the time will be extended, but so far, I can't think of any method or functions I can use to add the extra time. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code as following:

```
CountDownTimer.prototype.reset = function (duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}
```

and rewrite function `format` as :

```
function format(minutes, seconds) {
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    if (minutes < 2) {
        if (counter == 0) {
            //alert("Extending Time");
            timer.reset(timer.duration + 120);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way i can stop the countdown timer permanently ? I am trying to run it on partial views and when I get back to the page there are two timers

Answer (score 1):

You can add code in `CountDownTimer.prototype.start` before `setTimeout` like:

`this.instance = setTimeout(...)`

add function:

```
CountDownTimer.prototype.kill = function() { 
    clearTimeout(this.instance)
}
```

call function **`kill`** to stop timer permanently.

Comment: The only way to stop timer permanently is to call primitive function `clearTimeout(timer)`. Binding timer  to `CountDownTimer` instance so that you can track the timer in any other cases i.e **stop**

Comment: yeah, from looking at how you binded the timer to instance then cleartimeout i undestand that theoretically it would stop but when i try to add it in , it still doesnt? is something wrong with the way i call the function?

Comment: oh i used `this.instance = setTimeout(...)` instead of `that.instance = setTimeout(...)`